# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

Tags: android, json, kotlin, rxjava, gson

Я  новичок в JSON. Я пытаюсь распарисить JSON,  столкнулся с проблемой и не знаю, как ее решить. Проблема: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $ . Я чувствую, что это просто, но я не могу понять, что необходимо исправить. Мой код:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var request: Disposable? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            val o =
                Observable.create <String> {
                    val urlConnection =
                        URL("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=30").openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                    try {
                        urlConnection.connect()
                        if (urlConnection.responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                            it.onError(RuntimeException(urlConnection.responseMessage))
                        else {
                            val str = urlConnection.inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()
                            it.onNext(str)
                        }
                    } finally {
                        urlConnection.disconnect()
                    }
                }
                    .map { Gson().fromJson(it, Feed::class.java) }
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

            request = o.subscribe({
                for (item in it.items)
                    Log.d("test", "name: ${item.name}")

            }, {
                Log.d("test", "", it)
            })

    }
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        request?.dispose()
    }
}
class Feed(
    var items: List<FeedItem>
)
class FeedItem(
    val id: String,
    val name: String,
    val symbol: String,
    val price_usd: String,
    val percent_change_1h: String,
    val percent_change_24h: String,
    val percent_change_7d: String
)
```

Один из вариантов ожидаемого мной ответа выглядит следующим образом:

```
{
    "id": "iota",
    "name": "IOTA",
    "symbol": "MIOTA",
    "price_usd": "1.96153",
    "24h_volume_usd": "64054500.0",
    "percent_change_1h": "-0.65",
    "percent_change_24h": "3.12",
    "percent_change_7d": "4.43"
}
```

Comment: Сервис по ссылке возвращает не объект со списком элементов, а просто голый список элементов. На это и ругается gson: ожидался объект, а получили список.

Comment: спасибо большое за подсказку!)

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ, перепишите `Feed` таким образом

```
class Feed: ArrayList<FeedItem>()
```

чтобы отвечал структуре JSON-а.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное, сработало)